# scala spark convert a struct type column to json data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I trying to aggregate few fields in a dataset and transform them into json array format, I used concat_ws and lit functions to manually add the ":" separator, I am sure there should be some better way to do this, here is the code I tried so far,  I am on spark 2.0.1 version, so no luck with to_json function.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat_ws
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

object Zipper {
  val warehouseLocation = "file:///${system:user.dir}//spark-warehouse"
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("jsonconvert")
    .config("spark.master", "local")
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
    .getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
def main(args: Array[String]) = {

val df = Seq(
  ("john", "tomato", 1.99),
  ("john", "carrot", 0.45),
  ("bill", "apple", 0.99),
  ("john", "banana", 1.29),
  ("bill", "taco", 2.59)
).toDF("name", "food", "price")
df.show(false)



df.groupBy($"name")
  .agg(collect_list(struct(concat_ws(":",lit("food"),$"food"),concat_ws(":",lit("price"),$"price"))).as("foods"))
  .show(false)
}
} 



    +----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|name|foods                                                                         |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|john|[[food:tomato,price:1.99], [food:carrot,price:0.45], [food:banana,price:1.29]]|
|bill|[[food:apple,price:0.99], [food:taco,price:2.59]]                             |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Expected Output

```
    +----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|name|foods                                                                         |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|john|[{"food":"tomato","price":1.99}, {"food":"carrot","price":0.45}, {"food":"banana","price":1.29}]|
|bill|[{"food":"apple","price":0.99}, {"food":"taco","price":2.59}]                             |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Spark version prior to 2.1, try aggregate (`food`, `price`) by `name`, apply `toJSON` to the DataFrame, and extract JSON objects as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.groupBy($"name").agg(collect_list(struct($"food", $"price")).as("food_price")).
  toJSON.
  select(
    get_json_object($"value", "$.name").as("name"),
    get_json_object($"value", "$.food_price").as("foods")
  ).
  show(false)
// +----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// |name|foods                                                                                         |
// +----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// |john|[{"food":"tomato","price":1.99},{"food":"carrot","price":0.45},{"food":"banana","price":1.29}]|
// |bill|[{"food":"apple","price":0.99},{"food":"taco","price":2.59}]                                  |
// +----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: As, mentioned in the question, I am on a older spark version, which doesn't have to_json function readily available.

Comment: Missed that, my bad.  Please see whether the revised solution works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._




    val df = Seq(
      ("john", "tomato", 1.99),
      ("john", "carrot", 0.45),
      ("bill", "apple", 0.99),
      ("john", "banana", 1.29),
      ("bill", "taco", 2.59)
    ).toDF("name", "food", "price")



    val vkDF2 = df.groupBy("name").agg(collect_list(struct(col("food"),col("price"))).alias("vaquarkhan_json"))

    vkDF2.show()

**Results :**

+----+--------------------+
|name|     vaquarkhan_json|
+----+--------------------+
|john|[[tomato,1.99], [...|
|bill|[[apple,0.99], [t...|
+----+--------------------+

import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, food: string ... 1 more field]
vkDF2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, vaquarkhan_json: array<struct<food:string,price:double>>]
```